# Extract data from a multidimensional array where a given date string in found in the delimited string of a deep subarray

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering, delimited

I have this array containing my bookings:

```
$bookings[] = array(
    'booking_id' => '1', 
    'client_firstname' => 'Gareth', 
    'days' => array(
        array('day_id' => '2016-11-23,2016-11-24', 'room_id' => '2'),
        array('day_id' => '2016-11-25', 'room_id' => '4'),
        array('day_id' => '2016-11-26,2016-11-27,2016-11-28', 'room_id' => '2'),
    )
);
$bookings[] = array(
    'booking_id' => '2', 
    'client_firstname' => 'James', 
    'days' => array(
        array('day_id' => '2016-11-25,2016-11-26,2016-11-27,2016-11-28', 'room_id' => '5')
    )
);
$bookings[] = array(
    'booking_id' => '2', 
    'client_firstname' => 'Marco', 
    'days' => array(
        array('day_id' => '2016-11-24', 'room_id' => '5')
    )
);
```

---

## Explication of the array:

- The array shows the `booking_id` and the `client_name`.
- The array `days` contains the schedule of the client in the hotel. Each array in this `days` array explains which days and in which room the client is. If I have more than one line, the client change room.

---

## The wish

For a date I give, I need to get the bookings where into the `days array` the first date correspond to the date I give.

---

## Example

- Date I give is `2016-11-25`.
- I need to get:

```
`$bookings[] = array(
    'booking_id' => '1', 
    'client_firstname' => 'Gareth', 
    'days' => array(
        array('day_id' => '2016-11-25', 'room_id' => '4')
    )
);
$bookings[] = array(
    'booking_id' => '2', 
    'client_firstname' => 'James', 
    'days' => array(
        array('day_id' => '2016-11-25,2016-11-26,2016-11-27,2016-11-28', 'room_id' => '5')
    )
);`
```

---

## What I have try

```
$day_value = '2016-11-23';
$bookings_ = array();
foreach($bookings as $b){
    foreach($b['days'] as $day){
       if(in_array($day_value,explode(',',$day['day_id'][0]))){
         $bookings_[]  = $b;
       }
    }
}
print_r($bookings_);
```

But it returns me all the results into the bookings.

Comment: remove the `[0]` from `$day['day_id'][0]` and your example code works for me.

Comment: No, if I remove the [0], I will have all the array of the days array whereas I need only the 2nd one.

Comment: So you want to add these lines: `$b['days'] = $day; $bookings_[] = $b; break;` right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you think is `$day['day_id'][0]`?

It's the first symbol of `$day['day_id']` as latter is a string. So, nothing will be exploded by `,` in `$day['day_id'][0]`. And solution is to remove `[0]`:

```
foreach($bookings as $b){
    foreach($b['days'] as $day){
        if(in_array($day_value,explode(',',$day['day_id']))){
            // this string added:
            $b['days'] = $day;

            $bookings_[]  = $b;

            // btw, if your `$b['days']` has several elements
            // and in a couple of them there's a required date
            // then `$b` will be added to `$bookings_` several 
            // times, so probably you need `break`
            // break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, if I remove the `[0]`, I will have all the array of the `days` array whereas I need only the 2nd one.

Comment: Second one __what__?

Comment: Check my desired example I wrote in my question.

Comment: Tell me that you understand that `$day['day_id'][0]` is __NOT A STRING WITH COMMAS__